# need to position a table vertically middle of a div which has height of 500 px

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I want to position my table as vertical-align as middle and text-align as center  of the div which has height of 500px, but my table is just center aligned and it is not vertically aligned for middle of the div.

> /* CSS - I am refering the below css from a external file.
>
> ```
>     .login {
>         position: relative;
>         margin: 0 auto;
>         min-height: 500px;
>         display: block;
>         border: .5px solid;
>         border-color: lightgray;
>     }
>
>     .logintable {
>         position: relative;
>         border-style: solid;
>         border-color: lightgray;
>         border-width: 1.5px;
>         padding: 0px;
>         border-spacing: 0px;
>         text-align: center;
>         vertical-align: bottom;
>         left: 30%;
>       height: 50%;
>         bottom: 50%;
>     }*/
> </style> </head> <body>
>
> <div id="login" class="login">
>
>     <table class="logintable">
>         <tbody>
>             <tr>
>                 <td colspan="2">Log In</td>
>             </tr>
>             <tr>
>                 <td>
>                     <label id="lblUserName">User Name</label>
>                 </td>
>                 <td>
>                     <asp:textbox id="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
>                 </td>
>             </tr>
>             <tr>
>                 <td>
>                     <label id="lblPassword">Password</label>
>                 </td>
>                 <td>
>                     <asp:textbox id="txtPassword" runat="server" textmode="Password"></asp:textbox>
>                 </td>
>             </tr>
>
>             <tr>
>                 <td colspan="2">
>                     <asp:button id="LoginButton" runat="server" text="Login" onclick="LoginButton_Click" />
>                 </td>
>             </tr>
>         </tbody>
>     </table>
> </div> </body> </html>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to the table

```
position: absolute;
vertical-align: middle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vqfpwfeL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .logintable class:

```
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

try these classes in your css:

```
.login {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 500px;
    display: block;
    border: .5px solid;
    border-color: lightgray;
    padding:25% 0% 25% 0%
}

.logintable {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: lightgray;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50%;
}*/
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.logintable {
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: lightgray;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
}
```